# Closed forms at integer values for Euler products with Dirichlet $\chi_{4}(p^s)$. Could these be extended towards non-integer values?

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, dirichlet-series, euler-product

I was experimenting with the following products over all primes:

$$\prod_p \left(\frac{p^s}{{p^s-\sin\left(\dfrac{p^s \,\pi}{2}\right)}} \right)\,\cdot\,\prod_p \left(\frac{p^s+\sin\left(\dfrac{p^s \,\pi}{2}\right)}{p^s} \right)=\prod_p \left(\frac{p^s+\sin\left(\dfrac{p^s \,\pi}{2}\right)}{{p^s-\sin\left(\dfrac{p^s \,\pi}{2}\right)}} \right)$$

and used $p^s$ instead of $p$ in the Dirichlet character, i.e.: $\chi_{4}(p^s)=\sin\left(\dfrac{p^s \,\pi}{2}\right)$.

I then found that each factor on the LHS can be expressed in a closed form at integer values comprising of a rational and $\pi^n$. The RHS is purely rational and has a closed form as well:

For $s= $ even integer:

$$\large \lambda(s) \qquad \cdot \qquad \frac{\lambda(s)}{\lambda(2s)} \qquad=\qquad\frac{\lambda(s)^2}{\lambda(2s)} $$

$s=2 \large \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \frac{\pi^2}{8} \qquad  \cdot  \qquad \frac{12}{\pi^2} \qquad=\qquad \frac{3}{2}$
$s=4 \large \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \frac{\pi^4}{96} \qquad  \cdot  \qquad \frac{1680}{17\pi^4} \,\quad=\qquad \frac{35}{34}$
$s=6 \large \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \frac{\pi^6}{960} \quad \,\,\,  \cdot  \qquad \frac{665280}{691\pi^6} \,\,\,=\qquad \frac{693}{691}$

$\dots$

For $s= $ odd integer:

$$\large \beta(s) \qquad \cdot \qquad \frac{\beta(s)}{\lambda(2s)} \qquad=\qquad\frac{\beta(s)^2}{\lambda(2s)} $$

$s=1 \large \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \frac{\pi}{4} \qquad \,\,\, \cdot  \qquad \frac{2}{\pi} \,\,\qquad=\qquad \frac{1}{2}$
$s=3 \large \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \frac{\pi^3}{32} \qquad  \cdot  \qquad \frac{30}{\pi^3} \qquad=\qquad  \frac{15}{16}$
$s=5 \large \qquad \qquad\qquad \quad \,\,\,\,\,\frac{5\pi^5}{1536} \quad \,\,  \cdot  \qquad \frac{9450}{31\pi^5} \quad \,=\qquad  \frac{7875}{7936}$

$\dots$

where I used the [Dirichlet $\lambda$-](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletLambdaFunction.html) and [Dirichlet $\beta$-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), that each have closed form expressions.

**Question:**

Just like $\displaystyle \prod_p \left(\frac{p^s+1}{p^s-1}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}$ is valid for all $s \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(s)>1$, could there also be a way to extend the closed forms above towards non-integer values with $\Re(s)>\frac12$?

Comment: Please replace $\frac{p^s+1}{p^s-1}$ by $\frac{1+p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}$. And honestly looking at $a_n(s) = \prod_{p^k \| n} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} p^s)^k$ doesn't make any sense. Do you realize everything we can do with $\zeta(s)$, $L(s,\chi)$ is in the books ?

Comment: @reuns What exactly is the difference between $\frac{p^s+1}{p^s-1}$ and $\frac{1+p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}$ ? Just the formatting? You're right that there is a lot on $L(s,\chi)$ in the books, however assuming "everything" is there would imply that there's really nothing to discover anymore... Maybe this isn't new, but I just liked to find an Euler product that appears to flip between $L(s,\chi_{4,0})$ and $L(s,\chi_{4,1})$ at odd and even integers.

Comment: Nonsense. The natural way to interpolate between periodic sequences is using periodic sequences. Given how well studied $\zeta(s)$ has been, there is almost nothing new to discover. And it is true that everything we can do at your level is in the books.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Your last statement is probably also correct, however I will continue dreaming that one day I'll surprise you with something that isn't in the books yet... :-)